# Filtering latest tweets

Tags: java, processing, twitter4j

I am trying to filter the latest tweets with the words `sad, okay, joyful`.

When a tweet which has either word inside it, I would like it to print that tweet. But I would also like there to be a delay in the tweets which are printed. So about a 10 second delay between each tweet. For example:

If a tweet comes through : `@joker im so sad today`
Then I want that to print to the screen, and to the following message

System.out.println("*********************************************a sad tweet");

Then if a tweet comes through after this: `@programmer im joyful` 
Then 10 seconds after the last tweet I want that tweet to come through with the following message drawn to the screen.

System.out.println("*********************************************a joyful tweet");

And so on.

Below, I have made some code which allows you to filter the tweets, but im unsure of how to test and print a separate message for each tweet. I tried storing this in an Arraylist and retrieving each tweet with a message, but this doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?
Im using processing 2 and twitter4j 3
Any suggestions? Solutions

```
void GetTweetsByKeywords()
{

   List<String>mood = new ArrayList <String>();
   ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
   cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXX");
   cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXX");
   cb.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXX");
   cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXX");

   TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
   StatusListener statusListener = new StatusListener()
   {
      private int count = 0;
      private long originalTweetId = 0;

      @Override
      public void onStatus(Status status)
      {

          System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " : " + status.getText());

      } //en of the onStatus()
      public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice)
      {
          // should really remove deleted tweets here ...
      }

      public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses)
      {
      }

      public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
      // should really remove deleted location information here ...
      }

      public void onStallWarning(StallWarning stallWarning) {
      // should really do something about stalls here ...
      }
      @Override
      public void onException(Exception ex)
      {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

  }; //end of the listener
  String keywords[] = {"sad","okay","joyful"};
  for(int i=0; i<keywords.length; i++)
  {
      FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

      fq.track(keywords);

      twitterStream.addListener(statusListener);
      twitterStream.filter(fq);
      mood.add(//here i want to add the filtered tweets);
      System.out.println("Heres a filter :" + mood.get(i));

      if (mood.get(i).equals("sad"))
      {
         System.out.println("*********************************************a sad tweet");
      }
      else if (mood.get(i).equals("joyful"))
      {
        System.out.println("*********************************************a joyfull tweet");
      }
      else if(mood.get(i).equals("okay"))
      {
        System.out.println("*********************************************okay tweet");
      }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use a separate thread and a queue. Do this:

```
final Queue<Status> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Status>(10000);

new Thread(){
    // In your status listener, post tweets to the queue
    ...
        public void onStatus(Status status){
            queue.offer(status);
        }
    ...

    // Create TwitterStream instance, add query
    // and start listening
    twitterStream.filter(fq);
}.start();

while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    Status nextTweet = queue.take();
    System.out.println("Do stuff with tweet");
}
```